# I want to retrieve the current date and time nox textBox

Tags: c#, datetime, textbox

```
protected void ButtonPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        var macroController = new MacroController();
        var itens = macroController.ObterTodos(new Entities.FiltroMacro()

        {
            //NumeroLocomotiva = TextBoxNumeroLocomotiva.Text,
            DataInicio = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxDataInicio.Text + " " + TextBoxHoraInicio.Text),
            DataFim = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxDataFim.Text + " " + TextBoxHoraFim.Text)
```

my code now works as follows: inform the values ​​in textBox and returns me what is posted. But I'm wanting to return the current date and time of the system without I need to fill.

Comment: Replace `TextBoxDataInicio.Text` with `DateTime.Now.ToString()`. This is what you want?

Comment: You want to write current data and time in a textbox is that your question?

Comment: The current date and time is available in `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.UtcNow`).  What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: I want the (TextBoxDataInicio and TextBoxHoraInicio) and (TextBoxDataFim and TextBoxHoraFim). Come fill the current time and date of the system.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple, you could have just Googled this.

```
TextBoxHora.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("g"); // Just the time

TextBoxData.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("D"); // Just the Date 

TextBoxDataHora.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString(); // Complete date and Time

TextBoxDataHoraCompleta.Text = DateTime.Now;
```

Go to these links for more information.

- [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Not be able to implement my idea to code with the last example.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: To assemble the structure even when I try to implement your example in my code the syntax error. Could give me an example with textBox informed in question?

Comment: It wont give the syntax error now, I mistakenly wrote DateTime.Now() where as it should be DateTime.Now as DateTime.Now is a property.

Answer (score 0):

In the code I saw that you want the get the date from the text boxes, so: If you want to parse the date time and provide the format in one string you should use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method. For instance, see the usage in a sample console application:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2014$05$01", "yyyy$MM$dd", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
        Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}",parsedDate.Year);
        Console.WriteLine("Month: {0}",parsedDate.Month);
        Console.WriteLine("Day: {0}",parsedDate.Day);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

You can read [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at msdn for searching more information about the date formats.